# how to set Zxing View Finder Rectangle to portrait mode

Tags: android, zxing

I'm using the zxing 2.1 version, I need to capture the qr code in portrait mode, I've set the displayOrientation to "90" in CameraConfigurationManager.

Modified Methods,

```
CameraConfigurationManager->initFromCameraParameters(Camera camera)
                           -> setDesiredCameraParameters(Camera camera, boolean safeMode)
```

But problem in setting the ViewFinder to match for portrait mode,can some one help me on how to do this..

Sam

Comment: Here's what you can do with zxing 2.1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252791/how-to-show-zxing-camera-in-portrait-mode-on-android/16252917#16252917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following github project useful,
https://github.com/pplante/zxing-android

It's using zxing 1.7 source as a base.

Have useful info in this link too
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite that simple, since the orientation has to be set correctly as well, the UI orientation has to be set, and the UI has to be rewritten to have a landscape version. You also have to detect the camera's orientation, and account for the fact that it may be on the front vs back. It's about 5 things to get right rather than a one line change. Have a go at it, and ask specific questions about what you have tried in another SO question then.

Comment: I'm not clear about your answer,if you can expand what you mean by "5 things to get right rather than a one line change" i found this link and tried it http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178#c46 but still the rectangle box is not in center for portrait mode, how do i position the rectangle box?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work because there is more to change. Have you started by trying to implement other necessary changes like the ones discussed there?